# How to apply pagination load more function using PageController

Tags: flutter, dart, video-streaming, load

I am working on live video streaming application with flutter. Everything is working fine except load more function. i am loading first 10 records from server and when user reach to last video i want to load more 10 records. I am using page controller to control the video pages. how can i make load more function to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Below is my page controller class

```
class VideoListController {
  /// Construction method
  VideoListController();

  /// Snap to slide to realize page turning
  void setPageContrller(PageController pageController) {
    pageController.addListener(() {

      int pageIndex = pageController.page.round();

      _HomePageState home = _HomePageState();

      if(pageIndex==home.videoDataList.length)
      {
          home.loadMore();
          print("TAG loading more now");
      }

      var p = pageController.page;
      if (p % 1 == 0) {
        int target = p ~/ 1;
        if (index.value == target) return;
        //Play the current one, pause the others
        var oldIndex = index.value;
        var newIndex = target;
        playerOfIndex(oldIndex).seekTo(0);
        playerOfIndex(oldIndex).pause();
        playerOfIndex(newIndex).start();
        // carry out
        index.value = target;
      }
    });
  }

 
//Get specified index的player
FijkPlayer playerOfIndex(int index) => playerList[index];

  /// Total number of videos
  int get videoCount => playerList.length;

  /// Continue to add videos behind the current list and preload the cover
  addVideoInfo(List<VideoModel> list) {
    for (var info in list) {
      playerList.add(
        FijkPlayer()
          ..setDataSource(
            Glob.ITEM_BASE_URL + info.post_video,
            autoPlay: playerList.length == 0,
            showCover: true,
          )
          ..setLoop(0),
      );
    }
  }

  /// initialization
  init(PageController pageController, List<VideoModel> initialList) {
    addVideoInfo(initialList);
    setPageContrller(pageController);
  }

  /// Current video sequence number
  ValueNotifier<int> index = ValueNotifier<int>(0);

  /// Video list
  List<FijkPlayer> playerList = [];

  ///
  FijkPlayer get currentPlayer => playerList[index.value];

  bool get isPlaying => currentPlayer.state == FijkState.started;

  /// Destroy all
  void dispose() {
    // Destroy all
    for (var player in playerList) {
      player.dispose();
    }
    playerList = [];
  }
}


Below is load more function


Future<List<VideoModel>> loadMore() async {

    Video menu = await getVideos();

    if (menu.status == true) {
      print("TAG res success is true " + menu.message);
      setState(() {
        videoDataList.addAll(menu.data);
        start=videoDataList.length.toString();
        print("TAG start " + start);
      });

      _videoListController.addVideoInfo(menu.data);
    }
    else {
      print("No Data Found Paras");
    }
    return videoDataList;
  }


Future<Video> getVideos() {
    String data_type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    Map<String,String> headers = new Map();
    headers['Content-Type'] = data_type;

    return _netUtil.post(Glob.POST_LIST, body: {"count": count, "start": start,"type": type, "my_user_id": my_user_id},headers: headers).then((dynamic obj)
    {
      var results;
      bool success = obj["status"];
      print("TAG success =$success");
      if (success == true)
        results = Video.fromJson(obj);
      else
        results = Video.fromJsondata(obj);

      return results;
    });
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the problem with the current code?

Comment: @OMiShah The current code is working fine for fetching first 10 records, when user reached the last video it's not calling api to fetch next 10 records and that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're checking in the wrong way. You're actually checking the `pageIndex` value with the list size. The problem with that is `index` starts from `0` while `length` from `1` so `pageIndex` is never gonna match `home.videoDataList.length`. You have to check with `home.videoDataList.length - 1`

```
if(pageIndex == home.videoDataList.length - 1)
{
   home.loadMore();
   print("TAG loading more now");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it still not working.. I know index starts from 0 and length is always 1 number greater than the last index. I have tried length-1 already but it's not working. do you have any example which apply load more function on view pager instead of listview?